# Is there a way of getting a file name and inserting into Matlab script?

Tags: file, matlab, path

In a folder, I have both my `.m` file that contains the script and one imaging `.dcm` file that is the target of my analysis.

Folder structure:

```
Folder1/analysis.m
Folder1/meas_dynamic_123.dcm
Folder1/meas_123.dcm
Folder1/meas_345.dcm
```

My script (analysis.m) begins as follows:

```
target     =''; <== here should go only the filename that contains 'dynamic'
                    example: meas_dynamic_123.dcm

txt        = dir(target);

// etc
```

So I'm wondering if there is a way of when running `analysis.m` it will:

- automatically search the folder it's in,
- grab the filename of file containing string `dynamic` in the name,
- insert its name into `target` variable
- continue running the script

Does anyone have any pointers on how to achieve this? Using `ffpath`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should do:

```
f=dir('*dynamic*');
target=f(1).name;
```

Comment: this works on the command line but when I put it in the script I get an error `Function is not defined for 'struct' inputs.`

Comment: This is because you need to extract only the filename from the structure returned by `dir`. Try `txt=dir('*dynamic*');` `txt={txt.name};`

Answer (score 1):

Assume you are not in `Folder1` and you need to find it:

```
script_name = 'analysis';
script_full_path = which(script_name);      % get full path of the script
script_dir = fileparts( script_full_path ); % get the directory of the script
file_list = dir( [script_dir '/*dynamic*']);
name_list = {file_list.name};
```

`name_list` will be a cell array containing the file names with the keyword 'dynamic'.

Comment: thx will keep this for full path but for now using simpler approach from @oli

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `which(scriptname)`, consider using `mfilename('fullpath')`, which will directly give you the full path of the running m-file. Using `which` might break if you had multiple commands of the same name shadowed on the path.